# JSONObject (org.json) to JsonElement(com.google.gson)

Tags: java, json

I am writing a java code in which i need to convert a JSONObject to JsonElement.Is there any way using which i can convert a JSONObject (org.json) to JsonElement(com.google.gson)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way that always works is to serialize the object to JSON and then parse it again:

```
JSONObject myData = ...
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(myData.toString(), JsonElement.class);
```