# Returning an array of JSON objects when parsing a schema exception with Everit JSON Schema Validator

Tags: java, arrays, json, exception, jsonschema

I'm currently using a [JSON Schema Validator](https://github.com/everit-org/json-schema) in conjunction with Gson to handle exceptions and validate json requests made to an API.

The validator can return multiple exceptions when comparing a request with a schema. The sample from the repository is:

```
try {
  schema.validate(rectangleMultipleFailures);
}
catch (ValidationException e) {
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  e.getCausingExceptions().stream()
      .map(ValidationException::getMessage)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

And my implementation of the `try catch` (missing the catch obviously) is:

```
try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("SupplierSchemaIncoming.json")) {
    JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(inputStream));
    Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
    // Throws a ValidationException if requestJson is invalid:
    schema.validate(new JSONObject(requestJson));
}
catch (ValidationException ve) {
    System.out.println(ve.toJSON().toString());
}
```

As you can see above, one option is to return all of the errors as a single JSON.

```
{
    "pointerToViolation": "#",
    "causingExceptions": [{
        "pointerToViolation": "#/name",
        "keyword": "type",
        "message": "expected type: String, found: Integer"
    }, {
        "pointerToViolation": "#/type",
        "keyword": "type",
        "message": "expected type: String, found: Integer"
    }],
    "message": "2 schema violations found"
}
```

However, I'm stumped on how to get the exception to return an array of `SchemaError` objects (below) which I can parse however I want.

```
package domainObjects;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

public class SchemaError {
    @Expose
    String pointerToViolation;

    @Expose
    String keyword;

    @Expose
    String message;

    public SchemaError() {}

    public String getPointerToViolation() {
        return pointerToViolation;
    }

    public void setPointerToViolation(String pointerToViolation) {
        this.pointerToViolation = pointerToViolation;
    }

    public String getKeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }

    public void setKeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654988/jsonobject-org-json-to-jsonelementcom-google-gson) which recommended serialising the object from a JSONObject to a JSONElement and returning that. The `catch()` now has:

```
    catch (ValidationException ve) {            

        JSONObject jsonObject = ve.toJSON();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonElement element = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), JsonElement.class);

        return element;

    }
```